# Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found: android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have added ConstraintLayout 1.0.0 to my project as a dependency and it builds successfully. But in Android Studio 2.2 in activity_main.xml in Design tab I always receive this message:

> Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found:
>   - android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout (    Add constraint-layout library dependency to the project, Fix Build Path,
>   Edit XML, Create Class)  Tip: Try to build the project.  Tip: Try to
>   refresh the layout.

Because of that visual editor doesn't display components I add.

What to do?

Comment: compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta1' update your dependency

Comment: When I rebuild It gives error :`Couldn't find com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta1`

Comment: Please update your SDK and classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-beta3' it work in my Android studio

Comment: I did that but I got error: `Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3. Current version is 2.14.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in D:\Programs\androidworkspace\LayoutPlayspace\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-3.3-all.zip`

Comment: remove gradle folder then after try to build new gradle as well...

Comment: Removing .gradle folder and restart ide helped