# The following classes could not be found: - com.example.humsafardriver (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class) when i try constraint layout

Tags: android

Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found: android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
I have tried avery thing

Comment: You can check the same question in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29194479/android-studio-rendering-problems-the-following-classes-could-not-be-found)

Comment: It looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442240/rendering-problems-the-following-classes-could-not-be-found-android-support-con

Answer (score 1):

**Solution** in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29194479/android-studio-rendering-problems-the-following-classes-could-not-be-found)

You have to do two things:

- be sure to have imported right appcompat-v7 library in your project structure -> dependencies
- change the theme in the preview window to not an AppCompat theme. Try with Holo.light or Holo.dark for example.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't added required dependency for constraintlayout i guess. add this to your app/build.gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

If you already added, you might have to convert all your dependencies to androidX.